# xdebug 2.2.0RC2 strange error with vmware guest os?

Tags: vmware, xdebug

I've a vmware guest os with a webserver and xdebug 2.2.0RC2 installed and I want to open a debug session from my host to my virtual machine. On my host I've Opera and xdebug extension installed. When I load Komodo and try to connect to the xdebug it failed but when I try the xdebug extension from Opera sometimes I get this message in my virtual machine xdebug log file:

```
  Log opened at 2012-04-29 12:15:28
  I: Checking remote connect back address.
  I: Remote address found, connecting to 192.168.92.1:9000.
  I: Connected to client. :-)
  -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/
  xdebug" fileuri="file:///htdocs/typo3_src-4.7.0/typo3/install/index.php" 
  language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="5984" idekey="komodo-xdebug"><engine 
  version="2.2.0rc2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></
  author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 
  2002-2012 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
  -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/ 
   xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

  Log closed at 2012-04-29 12:15:58
```

The problem is my virtual machine is on vmnet8 with a NAT and it has a different ip then my virtual machine. The ip in the xdebug log is my vmnet8 adapter. From my host I can ping my webserver and ftp but I cannot telnet to port 9000. I've already port forwarding my port 80 and 9000 with vmware nat options but not the ftp port? When I enable xdebug with my opera xdebug extension I get the above message and then the site is stopping to load so the opera extension can see my virtual machine and xdebug but why not Komodo? Can Komdo listen to another server then localost without the debugproxy? Normally I use a reverse shell to tunnel my remote host to my local machine but this is special because I use a virtual machine on my local machine and I want to try the regular remote options.