# Cygwin reverse shell xdebug Windows 7 Komodo session not working?

Tags: cygwin, vmware, xdebug, komodo

I've a webserver with xdebug 2.0.3 and Komodo 6 with Windows 7 64 bit but I can't connect to xdebug? I've tried a reverse shell with cygwin and I can connect to my server however when I try the debugger option in Komodo it gives me an error. In Komodo I've open a remote ftp  session to load my file from the host. Normally with Linux it works with a reverse shell.

Edit: It's a bit on top of my head so I'm trying to debug my local virtual machine but Komodo gives me this error couldn't bind to local port 9000 and I don't have a firewall. when I enable debugging in the browser window with my opera extension I get success message client found in my xdebug log and when I load my html page but the connection is closed after the loading and it's not breaking at my breakpoint either. Here is the output from message log:

```
  Log opened at 2012-04-30 08:48:40
  I: Checking remote connect back address.
  I: Remote address found, connecting to 127.0.0.1:9000.
  I: Connected to client. :-)
  -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/
  xdebug" fileuri="file:///htdocs/typo3_src-4.7.0/index.php" language="PHP"       
  protocol_version="1.0" appid="5101" idekey="komodo-xdebug"><engine     
  version="2.2.0rc2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></
  author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 
  2002-2012 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
  -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/ 
  xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

 Log closed at 2012-04-30 08:48:41
```

My webserver is a lighttpd with FastCGI but that shouldn't be the problem because I already got it working with a remote host and a reverse shell but not in Windows 7 and with Vmware or in Vmware? I'm currently reading this post http://forums.netbeans.org/topic1513-30.html and I hope it helps.

Also I cannot see that a server is listening on port 9000. Is this a Vmware problem?

EDIT: I got it working on my virtual machine but I'm still interested in solving this issue:

1. xdebug connecting from host to virtual machine
2. xdebug connecting from host to remote machine (it works for me but only with a reverse shell)
3. xdebug connectiong from virtual machine to remote machine (didn't test it yet)

What can be interesting to is developement in Windows 7:

1. xdebug connecting from Windows 7 to remote machine
2. xdebug connection from Windows 7 to virtual machine

Comment: You're not providing enough information: no php.ini settings, and "gives me an error" doesn't help either. Also try making a remote debugging log (see: http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log)

Comment: @Derick: I already give some information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372119/xdebug-2-2-0rc2-strange-error-with-vmware-guest-os. I've also installed the latest xdebug to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [debugger connection preferences](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.0/prefs.html#DebuggerConnection) to set the IP address of the virtual machine as the [debugger proxy](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.0/debugger.html#dbgp_proxy). Change the port that Komodo listens to from the default value of 9000 to [a system provided free port](http://community.activestate.com/node/7848), 8080, or whatever port your virtual host or localhost is running.